# Como interromper e devolver ao xhtml erro para exibir no <p:messages>

Tags: java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Tenho um processamento de um `<p:dialog>` dentro deste dialog tenho um `<p:messages>`.

`<p:messages id="msg-dialog" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"  />`

As mensagens dos `required="true"` dos `inpuText` funcionam perfeitamente.

Mas ao processar uma submissão no Bean por exemplo:

```
    if (!ValidaCPF.isCPF(itemEdicao.getCpf())) {
            itemEdicao.setSituacao("I");
            messages.error("CPF Inválido!");
            msgErro = "CPF Inválido";
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(Arrays.asList("frm:msg-dialog","frm:itens-table"));
        }
```

Não consigo fazer com que a mensagem seja exibida. Meus `messages` é uma classe extendida de FacesMessages e nela quando executo:

`messages.error()` ou `messages.info()` - é enviado o parâmetro (abaixo a implementação)

```
public void info(String message) {
    add(message, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
}

public void error(String message) {
    add(message, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
}
```

Como faço para que o xhtml reconheça o erro e não feche o `<p:dialog>`

Segue o código onde o `hide` é executado:

```
<p:commandButton id="btn-salvar" value="Salvar"
    action="#{solicitacaoRHBean.salvarItem()}" process="item-dialog"
    disabled="#{solicitacaoRHBean.id == null}"
    oncomplete="if (! args.validationFailed) PF('edicaoItemDialog').hide()"
    update="msg-dialog painel-dialog itens-table">
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: `painel-dialog` é o id do dialog ou um painel dentro dele?

Comment: Rafael é um `<p:panelGrid>`, do diálogo é `item-dialog`.

Comment: Pelo que to vendo o problema pode estar nesse oncomplete, acho que ele esta fechando independente da sua condição. Já tentou fechar só pelo seu bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recebi a resposta de um amigo fora o SO. Implementei e funcionou.

Segue:

`import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;`

(...)

`RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
 context.addCallbackParam("validationFailed", true);`

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa pegar o contexto.
Pode se utilizar o do Javax, Jakarta ou de algum outro.. nesse caso vou usar o do primefaces

```
import org.primefaces.context.PrimeRequestContext;
```

Depois busque o contexto que você está, insira o valor do parâmetro que precisa e insira a mensagem que quer mostrar.

```
PrimeRequestContext context = PrimeRequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getCallbackParams().put("validationFailed", true);
MessagesHandler.addErrorMessage("Validação falhou!");
```

O messageHandler pode ser criado com essa classe:

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

    public class MessagesHandler {
    
        public static void addErrorMessage(String message) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, ""));
        }
    
        public static void addInfoMessage(String message) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, ""));
        }
    }
```

Lembrando que para as mensagens aparecerem precisa ter algum desses dois itens configurados no form.

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" closable="true"/>

<p:growl showDetail="true" life="10000"/>
```